# Found nil when adding view controller view to subview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with a table view, and need to add it as a sub view to another view controller, but when I add the view controller's view I get a nil pointing to the table. All the connections are there, but unable to crack the reason why it crashes.

Child Controller

```
class childController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

Parent Controller

```
func presentChildController() {
    let childVC = childController()
    self.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is completely illegal:

```
func presentChildController() {
    let childVC = childController()
    self.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
}
```

You cannot simply create a view controller, grab its view, and stuff its view into your own view. If you want your view controller (`self`) to function as a *parent view controller*, and `childController` to function as a child view controller, there is a [careful dance](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers) you have to do — and you are not doing that dance. Therefore, `childVC` (your `childController`) *goes out of existence* immediately, and that is the cause of the `nil` crash you are experiencing.

Another possible cause, by the way, is that if your `childController` is designed in the storyboard, `childController()` is the wrong way to instantiate it — the table view in the storyboard will never come into existence. You have to make sure the view controller's view is the view you have designed.